# Training loss almost zero using the tensorflow's object detection with custom dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I'm trying to train and object detection with the Tensorflow Object detection API and with my custom dataset. When I'm training with my tfrecord file I get a loss looking like this :

```
INFO:tensorflow:Recording summary at step 0.
INFO:tensorflow:global step 1: loss = 0.0340 (4.919 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 2: loss = 0.0340 (0.202 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 3: loss = 72.7242 (0.216 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 4: loss = 0.0340 (0.206 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 5: loss = 0.0342 (0.191 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 6: loss = 0.0344 (0.204 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 7: loss = 0.0347 (0.200 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 8: loss = 0.0349 (0.207 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 9: loss = 0.0352 (0.184 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 10: loss = 0.0355 (0.216 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 11: loss = 0.0358 (0.199 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 12: loss = 44.0913 (0.237 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 13: loss = 0.0365 (0.230 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 14: loss = 0.0368 (0.214 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 15: loss = 0.0372 (0.227 sec/step)
```

When I freeze the model and I try to test the inference, it completely fails to produce any bounding box that make sense.

I've tried many things so far. I've manually checked the content of my tfrecord file (meaning that I've extracted the binary jpegs and bounding boxes from my tfrecord to visualize them) and they seem fine.

The bounding boxes are correctly placed on top of my targets and the training images and bboxes look good. I'm not sure what could be causing this kind of error, especially given the fact that I've checked my custom tfrecord file.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How many classes do you have and what is the learning rate that you use?

Comment: I've got 1 class (I want to be to detect persons in the frame). My learning rate is 0.004.